# swfobject not sending along flashvars

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, swfobject, flashvars

I am using swfobject to pass along flashvars to flash/as3, but i cannot get it to work.

The first code repent my attempt at using swfobject:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var flashvars = {
        testVar:"123"
    };

    swfobject.embedSWF("falsh.swf", "flashDiv", "990", "600", "10.0.0", false, flashvars);

</script>

<div id="flashDiv"></div>
```

The second code is my attempt to do the same thin using the  tag

```
<object data="falsh.swf?testVar=123"
width="990" height="600" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="quality" value="high" /></object>
```

For some unknown reason only the second code block successfully sends along the flashvars.

Do anyone have an idea what is wrong? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the AS3 code you are using to read the flashvars?

Answer (score 0):

swfobject requires the name + id attributes to be set in order to pass the flashvars